# Understand a step in the derivation of the Stirling's approximation

Tags: numerical-methods, approximation

The Stirling's approximation of the factorial function is defined as:

$$n! \sim \sqrt{2 \pi n} \left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n$$

This [Wikipedia's derivation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation#Derivation) starts by using the logarithm of $n!$

> $$\ln n! = \ln 1 + \ln 2 + ... + \ln n$$

And then it says

> **The right-hand side of this equation minus**
>
> **$${\displaystyle {\tfrac {1}{2}}(\ln 1+\ln n)={\tfrac {1}{2}}\ln n} $$**
>
> is the approximation by the trapezoid rule of the integral
>
> $${\displaystyle \ln n!-{\tfrac {1}{2}}\ln n\approx \int _{1}^{n}\ln x\,{\rm {d}}x=n\ln n-n+1}$$
>
> ...

Before proceeding I of course need to understand every step, but I'm not understanding the text that I marked in bold.

What I understand from that statement is that *we substract an equation, i.e. ${\displaystyle {\tfrac {1}{2}}(\ln 1+\ln n)={\tfrac {1}{2}}\ln n} $, from the right hand side of the previous equation, i.e. $\ln n! = \ln 1 + \ln 2 + ... + \ln n$, which is $\ln 1 + \ln 2 + ... + \ln n$*. This does not make sense at all to me.

Could someone explain me what it's meant by that statement?

I must be honest, a great percentage of the times I don't understand something similar to this is because of the way things are explained in English, not because of the formulas. (Please, mathematicians, learn to write well!)

Comment: What exactly is unclear ? The trapezoid-rule states that the integral is approximately $1/2\ln(1)+\ln(2)+\ln(3)+\cdots+\ln(n-1) +1/2\ln(n)$

Comment: There is nothing to learn on our side. The RHS of an equation is just what is written on the right of the equality sign, so the *the RHS of the previous equation minus something* has the obvious meaning: what is written in the right part of the previous line, minus something.

Comment: In our case, *something* is $\frac{1}{2}\left(\log(1)+\log(n)\right)$, that is $\frac{1}{2}\log n$.

Comment: No, because you do not subtract $\log(1)+\log(2)+\ldots+\log(n)$ from $\frac{1}{2}\log(n)$, you do the opposite.

Comment: What you see is the author's personal style of writing. What it says *does* make sense, at the same time the sentence can be framed in a better manner.

Comment: What else *The RHS of the previous equation minus three* could mean?!

Comment: You are not subtracting an equation from another equation (that means nothing), you are subtracting a number ($\frac{1}{2}\log n$) from another number (the RHS of the previous equation).

Comment: Call them as you like, but $\log(1)+\ldots+\log(n)$ and $\frac{1}{2}\log(n)$ are numbers, not equations.

Comment: I really cannot see any ambiguity in the bold part, there is only one meaningful interpretation of what is written here.

Comment: @Nuncameesquecideti Do not overthink this.

Answer (score 1):

The trapezoid with base $[k,k+1]$ has area

$$\frac12\big(\ln k+\ln(k+1)\big)\;;$$

when you sum these over $k=1,\ldots,n-1$, you get

$$\frac12\ln 1+\ln 2+\ln 3+\ldots+\ln(n+1)+\frac12\ln n\;,$$

because every height except the first ($\ln 1$) and the last ($\ln n$) appears twice, once as the righthand height of a trapezoid and then again as the lefthand height of the next trapezoid. This is the same as

$$(\ln 1+\ln 2+\ldots+\ln n)-\left(\frac12\ln 1+\frac12\ln n\right)\;.$$

It doesn’t actually say that you’re subtracting an equation from an equation: it says that you’re subtracting the quantity $\frac12(\ln 1+\ln n)$ from the quantity $\ln 1+\ldots+\ln n$ (which happens to be $\ln n!$), and that this quantity that you’re subtracting can be simplified to $\frac12\ln n$ (since $\ln 1=0$).

Comment: I think there is just a language issue here, not a real mathematical problem.

Answer (score 0):

We start with the equality

$$\log(n!)=\log(1)+\log(2)+\cdots +\log(n)$$

Then, note that

$$\begin{align}
\log(n!)-\frac12 (\log(1)+\log(n))&=\frac12 \log(1)+\log(2)+\cdots +\log(n-1)+\frac12 \log(n)\\\\
&\approx \int_1^n \log(x)\,dx\\\\
&=n\log(n)-n+1
\end{align}$$

Since the logarithm is concave, the trapezoidal rule approximation provides a lower bound.  Therefore, we find from $(1)$ that

$$n!<e\sqrt{n}\left(\frac ne\right)^n $$

Comment: I think there is just a language issue here, not a real mathematical problem.